# dynamically add content to a div that saves with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

Is there anyway to dynamically add content to a div that saves even after you close the html page?

Something like this but this disappears as soon as you close or refresh.

http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/04/14/how-to-dynamically-add-content-to-a-div-via-javascript/

Thank you.

Comment: Store it on DB or localStorage. Part of the link you provided gives example on `Cookie`. You can use that also.

Comment: can it be stored on an excel data base?

Comment: That is more complicated than using localStorage or DB or Cookie

Comment: What DB are you referring too -  JQuery?

Comment: DB like database

Comment: Wouldn't I need php for that?

Comment: Yes. If you dont want backend your options are localStorage or cookie

Answer (score 0):

If you want data to persist even after page is closed you should use local storage.

In that case data will persist, till user explicitly clears cache

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp